# topology generated by irreducible componets of $\Gamma$-invariant closed sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, model-theory

For an analytic space $U$ equipped with an action of a group $\Gamma$,
call a subset $Z\subseteq U$ $\Gamma$-closed iff
it is a closed analytic subset and each of its irreducible components
is an irreducible component of a  $\Gamma$-invariant closed analytic set.

When do $\Gamma$-closed sets form a topology? Does it have a name
and are there any references discussing it ?

> What I want to know is the following: Under what conditions the following is  true:
>
> (i) $\Gamma$-closed sets form a topology.
>   (ii) for an analytic map $f:U\rightarrow U'$, the map $f:U/\Gamma \rightarrow U'/\Gamma'$ being closed and well-defined
>      implies  $f_*:U \rightarrow U'$ is closed as well in the topology of $\Gamma$- and $\Gamma'$-closed sets ?

For (i), it is enough to prove that the intersection of two $\Gamma$-closed
analytically irreducible closed sets is $\Gamma$-closed.

I am mostly interested in the case when $\Gamma$ is the topological fundamental group
of a complex algebraic variety acting on its univeresal covering space $U_A$.
Informally, the idea is to define a somewhat "finer" variant of the etale topology (
induced on the inverse limit of finite etale covers of $A(C)$.) For $\Gamma$ the algebraic
fundamental group and $U$ the inverse limit as above, both (i) and (ii) are easy.

There is a proof of this under assumption that $U$ and $U'$ are universal covering spaces of
projective algebraic varieties with subgroup separable (aka lerf)  fundamental groups,
by a rather ugly technical argument and not quite in this form ( [reference, p.11 and p.20](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1377)).
When $A(C)$ is a group, probably it also follows from a purely algebraic proof in [a model theory paper](http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/reprint/rnt057?ijkey=YGjgDqBoUzRG9u3&keytype=ref)
(which also generalised to prime characteristic).